# Apache <Files> correct syntax/load config only if find a specified file

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I'm trying a condition in my httpd.conf to load some options only if find a specific file. But it is not working :(

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c> #check if php fast-cgi is loaded
    <Files /cgi-bin/php.fcgi> #check if php.fcgi exists in document root folder
        AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
        Action php5-fastcgi /cgi-bin/php.fcgi
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

I want this to not to be obliged to create this file in every vhost that I made. If I load the module without this file, the site doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't**. `AddHandler` and `Action` directive can be only appear in: server config, virtual host, directory and .htaccess context:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_actions.html#action